# Use LED on pin 13 again after using the SD library

Tags: led, pins, sd-card

*The question in short:*
On an Arduino UNO or Nano using the [SD library](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/SD), is it somehow possible to use the LED on pin 13 (or any other pin that is used by the library) again after finishing all SD operations?

*Detailed explanation:*
In my sketch, during setup() I need to read some data from a file on the SD card, which is being closed again before leaving setup().

Now, I wanted to use the LED on pin 13 during loop() as a status indicator for the user, but it seems that after SD.begin(), pin 13 (and its LED) cannot be used as an OUTPUT anymore.

Here is a minimum sketch to show the behavior. It doesn't matter if I try to turn on the LED right after the call to SD.begin() in setup() or in loop():

```
#include <SD.h>
#include <SPI.h>

#define SD_CS  4
#define LED    13

void setup() {
  pinMode(LED, OUTPUT);

  // This still works:
  digitalWrite(LED, HIGH);
  delay(1000);
  digitalWrite(LED, LOW);

  SD.begin(SD_CS);

  // This does not work anymore:
  digitalWrite(LED, HIGH);
  delay(1000);
  digitalWrite(LED, LOW);
}

void loop() {}
```

Answer (score 10):

It is possible to use the LED on pin 13 again by disabling the SPI bus that is used by the SD library to read/write data to/from the SD card. To disable the SPI bus, simply call `SPI.end()` after closing the file on the SD card.

Comment: Agreed. Betwen `SPI.begin()`  and `SPI.end()` the hardware takes over that pin.

Comment: Does anyone know, why the SD library has no `.end()`? Apparently you don't have to explicitly call `SPI.begin()` in your sketch, as `SD.begin()` seems to wrap this. So I think, a call to `SPI.end()` should also be wrapped in some complementary method like `SD.end()`. Should this be filed as a bug report/wishlist item to the library developers? Or is there any reason why there is no method like this?

Comment: Sounds odd to me. You could query it with the developers.

Comment: Any updates on your followup question @JohannesMaibaum?

Comment: @JaroslavZáruba: No, actually. I just checked the [online reference for the SD library](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/SD) again, but still there is no `SD.end()` or similar. But simply calling `SPI.end()` worked and works for me.